# How to insert a StringBuilder element into a GWT app?

Tags: java, gwt

So, I am getting as return parameter from an already established code a `StringBuilder` element, and I need to insert it into my GWT app. This `StringBuilder` element has been formatted into a table before returning.

For more clarity, below is the code of how `StringBUilder` is being generated and what is returned.

```
private static String formatStringArray(String header, String[] array, int[] removeCols) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder("<table bgcolor=\"DDDDDD\" border=\"1\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"3\">");

    if (removeCols != null)
        Arrays.sort(removeCols);

    if (header != null) {
        buf.append("<tr bgcolor=\"99AACC\">");
        String[] tokens = header.split(",");
        //StringTokenizer tokenized = new StringTokenizer(header, ",");
        //while (tokenized.hasMoreElements()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            if (removeCols == null || Arrays.binarySearch(removeCols, i) < 0) {
                buf.append("<th>");
                buf.append(tokens[i]);
                buf.append("</th>");
            }
        }
        buf.append("</tr>");
    }

    if (array.length > 0) {
        for (String element : array) {
            buf.append("<tr>");
            String[] tokens = element.split(",");
            if (tokens.length > 1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
                    if (removeCols == null || Arrays.binarySearch(removeCols, i) < 0) {
                        buf.append("<td>");
                        buf.append(tokens[i]);
                        buf.append("</td>");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Let any non tokenized row get through
                buf.append("<td>");
                buf.append(element);
                buf.append("</td>");
            }
            buf.append("</tr>");
        }
    } else {
        buf.append("<tr><td>No results returned</td></tr>");
    }

    buf.append("</table>");
    return buf.toString();
}
```

So, above returned `buf.toString();` is to be received in a GWT class, added to a panel and displayed... Now the question is: **how to make all this happen?**

I'm absolutely clueless as I'm a newbie and would be very thankful for any help.

Regards,
Chirayu

Comment: Why do you create HTML entities from strings? You can create GWT UI gadgets (on client side) and build them as needed, using readable Java code.

Comment: @Eyal, thanks for your advice, I was trying to use the already written code, which returns a StringBuilder element and integrate it into GWT part which I'm doing.
The existing code is kinda complicated, and I'm on my internship, finishing soon so time was a constraint. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you be more specific, Chirayu? The "already established code" (is that a serlvet? Does it run on server side or client side?) that supposedly returns a `StringBuilder`, obviously returns a `String`, which can be easily transferred via GWT-RPC, JSON, etc.
But like Eyal mentioned, "you are doing it wrong" - you are generating HTML code by hand, which is additional work, leads to [security holes](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/security_for_gwt_applications.html) (XSS, etc) and is more error-prone. The correct way would be:

- Instead of generating the view/HTML code on the server (I'm assuming the above code is executed on the server), you just fetch the relevant data - via [any transport](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html) that is available in GWT
- On the client, put the data from the server in some nice Widgets. If you prefer to work with HTML directly, check out [UiBinder](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html). Otherwise, the old [widgets, composites, etc](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomWidgets.html) way is ok too.

This way, you'll minimize the data sent between the client and the server and get better separation (to take it further, check out [MVP](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture.html)). Plus, less load on the server - win-win.

And to stop being a newbie, RTFM - it's all there. Notice that all the links I've provided here lead to the official docs :)

Comment: "And to stop being a newbie" you will do pretty well as a psychotherapist :D [pun intended]

Comment: Thanks, Ashwin, it's always good to have a backup plan ;) I don't mind helping with even the simplest problems, unless I see that the person asking did not do his/her homework (jeez, I sound like a teacher). On the other hand, I'm kind of jealous of Chirayu, because he gets to play around with GWT for his internship :D (although I understand that getting shoved into the middle of GWT can be confusing and frustrating - you want to write a simple app, and suddenly you should know about MVP, UiBinder, different transports, security implications, optimization tricks, etc...)

Comment: @Ashwin, I wish I could crack a nasty pun at You, but sadly I'm a newbie(READ : ASS), and You are an expert.
@Igor, I have not done my homework, but that was because of a time-constraint, I',m a C/C++ developer, thrown into java development environment at internship, with already existing code, for one part of which I'm integerating GWT. Sadly I'm stuck, have 7 days left, trying to wrap up things, and confused.

Comment: @Igor, I am going into another internship after this, in 2 weeks(will be studying and working, helps me go through college), and I plan to use GWT&java the right way, i.e., Study every aspect regarding it. 

Can You tell me what all should I be doing keeping in mind my C/C++ background, or does this qualify as a new question ?! I'm asking boz I'm kinda scared that if its a stupid question then people won't participate in answering it at all, and rather I'l be said serious stuff about 'this is not the right way to do this-that'. I wanna do it the right way in next internship... I'l be thankful.

Comment: I understand your situation, Chirayu, that's why I'm providing answers and comments here. Actually, I also came from C++ to GWT :) And I've already answered your question above - without any specifics about your project (what does it use to communicate between server-client? Does it use UiBinder? Which GWT version?), I can't provide any source (and I'm rather reluctant to do so - all the code samples are in the docs or in the GWT samples). But do write if something is unclear :)

Comment: @Igor, thanks as always for your insight....I guess some battles we have to fight on our own in totality. 

Cheerz!

Answer (score 0):

Q.: How to use StringBuilder for HTML processing in a GWT app?

A.: Use [SafeHtmlBuilder](https://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/safehtml/shared/SafeHtmlBuilder.html)